# Normalization of Haar measure

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

The following was stated in my course on automorphic forms and I think there is at least missing an assumption.

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group and $H\subseteq G$ compact.
Then we can fix a Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ by requiring $\mu(H)=1$.
Here a Haar measure is locally finite, inner regular and left invariant measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $G$.

Setting $G=\Bbb{R}$ and $H=\{-1,0,1\}$ which is a compact subgroup of $G$ that has Lebesgue measure $0$, the above is clearly not possible.
I have already ruled out the possible problem that $H$ has infinite measure by using the local finiteness of the measure.

So am I missing something or should be added $H\subseteq G$ compact that has nonzero Haar measure (for any non trivial ($\not \equiv 0$) Haar measure)?

Comment: You are right that you can't normalize the haar measure with respect to zero measure compact set. (It will only work if the measure is positive). Any Haar measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is a constant multiplication of the Lebesgue measure (at least for sets that are both Borel and Lebesgue measurable)

Comment: In your example $H$ is not a subgroup!

Comment: Of course, you are right, but I may just take $H=\{0\}$ and everything is fine, I somehow mixed up whether dealing with a multiplicative or additive group.

Comment: Are you sure that the statement was as written? Could it have been that the Haar measure $\nu$ of $H$ is normalized requiring $\nu(H)=1$?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I confirmed with the professor that there was an assumption missing, as for example that $H$ should be open, too.
The existence of such an $\nu$ is trivial when knowing that compact sets have finite Haar measure. (and that those Haar measures exist)

Comment: For open $H$ it is trivial as well.

Comment: If $H$ is only open and not closed such $\nu$ does not exist.
For the assertion in the OP open is sufficient but this still has to be shown.
It is not hard but I would not call it trivial to show that open sets have positive measure. (if you don't have the right idea)

Comment: Yes, if you have to show that it is not trivial.